# how to use gem zero-clipboard-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeroclipboard

I added gem [zero-clipboard-rails](https://github.com/nragaz/zero-clipboard-rails) to Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and don't understand what is the next step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zero-clipboard-rails doesn't work with the latest Rails Version.

I just released a gems to solve this issue.

- [zeroclipboard-rails](https://github.com/HaNdTriX/zeroclipboard-rails).

Look at the github-pages for usage instructions.